# Problem on matrices : $\dim E\leq n^2-(n-r)^2-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following problem :

Let $E$ be a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ that contains no invertible matrix.

Let $r=\max\{rank(M)\mid M\in E\}$

Show that $\dim E\leq n^2-(n-r)^2-1$

---

I don't know how to do this.

We have obviously $\dim E=n^2$, and I guess that he $(n-r)^2$ is due to the rank of the space with invertible matrixes, but I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: Do you know the linear algebra theorem which says that a matrix has rank $\le r$ if and only if all its $(r+1) \times (r+1)$ minors are zero? This would probably help.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I haven't seen it that way, but doesn't that follow from the Laplace expansion of the matrix of rank $\leq r$?

Comment: What follows from Laplace expansion? Your question or the linear algebra theorem? The linear algebra theorem, yes. Your question I'm not sure.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I was just talking about the theorem, since it was the first time I encountered it. User TedShifrin told me that a result on matrices manifolds gave us that $\dim \{\text{matrices with rank }r\}=n^2-(n-r)^2$, but it involves complex theorems I do not know.

Comment: What does "subspace" mean here? Vector subspace? Is dimension the dimension of a vector space? It could be some other kind of subspace (topological subspace, submanifold, I don't know...)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Vector subspace, and dimension of a vector space

Comment: $M_n(\Bbb R)$ is a subspace which contains non invertible matrices and such that the bound does not hold.

Comment: @leo 'Let E be a subspace of Mn(ℝ) that contains no invertible matrix.' $M_n[\mathbb{R}]$ contains invertible matrixes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a matrix $A\in E$ with maximal rank $r$. By choosing two suitable bases on $\mathbb R^n$, I can assume that $A$ has the form
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0_{n-r} \end{pmatrix} .
$$
Now any $B\in E$ must have this $(n-r)\times (n-r)$ block of zeros in its bottom right corner; otherwise we could take the linear combination $A+\epsilon B$ with a small $\epsilon>0$ and obtain a matrix of bigger rank.

Let's call this space of matrices with this block of zeros in the bottom right corner $F$. Then, as just observed $E\subset F$. However, $E$ is clearly not all of $F$ since $F$ contains matrices of bigger rank. Thus
$$
\dim E < \dim F = n^2- (n-r)^2 .
$$

Comment: I do not fully understand how choosing two suitable bases allows us to put $A$ in the form $A = \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0_{n-r} \end{pmatrix}$, what are you exactly using here ?

Comment: @TheGame Any matrix of rank $r$ is congruent to $ \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0_{n-r} \end{pmatrix}$. To see this, take a basis $(e_{r+1},e_{r+2},\ldots,e_n)$ of ${\sf Ker}(A)$ and complete it into a basis ${\cal E}=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$. Then, the family $(A(e_1),A(e_2),\ldots,A(e_r))$ is linearly independent ; complete it into a basis ${\cal F}=A(e_1),A(e_2),\ldots,A(e_r),f_{r+1},\ldots,f_n)$. Then the matrix of $A$ with respect to bases $\cal E$ and $\cal F$ is exactly what we want.

Comment: @TheGame: Yes, this (= Ewan's comment) is exactly what I had in mind.